# Why atom deposition is simulated with the NVE ensemble?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, molecular-dynamics

In a typical deposition problem the substrate (or the 'host') is at a given temperature (and surrounded by a thermal bath), while the deposited species usually have a different temperature, which, a while after deposition, equilibrates to the substrate temperature.

Why then in [this LAMMPS example file](https://github.com/lammps/lammps/blob/master/examples/deposit/in.deposit.atom) an NVE ensemble is used for a deposition problem? The number of atoms in the simulation box increases over time, which means total energy is not fixed. Wouldn't NVT make more sense for a deposition problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is, in fact an NVT ensemble. The topmost layer of atoms of the substrate are coupled to a Langevin thermostat via

```
fix     2 mobile langevin 1.0 1.0 0.1 587283
fix     3 mobile nve
```

All other particles are not coupled to a thermostat, but this is will still simulate an NVT ensemble.

Comment: 1) the deposited atoms have `fix 1 addatoms nve` - why? 2) why after defining a langevin for the mobile atoms, an nve is defined for the same group?

Comment: 1) The deposition takes place in vacuum. Thus, the deposited atoms are not coupled to a thermostat. In the experiment only the substrate is connected to a temperature control. In the simulation, only the substrate atoms are connected to the thermostat. 2) `fix langevin` adds a random force to the particles, but does not perform time integration. This is done with the `fix nve` command. See the documenataion for [fix langevin](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/fix_langevin.html)